# Payment Services Exception Domain verification failed for merchantId

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I verified my domain successfully via Apple Developer Account. But, when I try to call Apple's registerMerchant API they respond with:

**statusMessage**: Payment Services Exception Domain verification failed for merchantId...
**errorMessage**=\"exception decoding Hex string: invalid characters encountered in Hex string\""
**statusCode**: 400

Did anyone encounter this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple was expecting to find a specific domain-verification-file (that they provided us). When I uploaded the correct file, the issue was resolved.